Independence of sample mean and variance among samples with infinite second moment
It's a well-known fact in statistics that the independence of the sample mean and variance characterise the Gaussian distribution in the sense that, if $X_1, \dotsc, X_n$ are iid and $\sum_{j=1}^n X_j$ is independent of $\sum_{j=1}^n (X_j - \bar{X})^2$, then the $X_j$ have a Gaussian distribution.
The canonical references for this fact seem to be Geary The Distribution of "Student's" Ratio for Non-Normal Samples (1936), where it is proved by showing that the joint cumulants of the sample mean and variance are all zero, and Lukacs A Characterization of the Normal Distribution (1942), where it is proved by solving a second-order differential equation for the characteristic function of $X_j$.
However, as far as I can tell, both of there proofs make moment assumptions on $X_j$; Geary assumes that the sample mean has all cumulants, while Lukacs assumes that the characteristic function of the sample variance is differentiable at zero.
Other proofs that I have found have all made some version of the above assumptions.
In my own attempts to prove this, the weakest condition that I can come up with is that the characteristic function of $X_j$ is twice-differentiable on a dense set, which is a moderate weakening of the second moment condition but isn't radically different from it as far as I can tell.
Does anyone have a reference to the result (if it's even true) that independence of the sample mean and variance characterise the Gaussian distribution even if we don't a priori assume the existence of any moments?

What is $\bar{X}$? Is this the expectation (which is assumed to exist), or the sample mean $\bar{X}:=(X_1+\ldots+X_n)/n$?

This is true without any a priori assumptions on the second moment.
A. M. Kagan, Yu. V. Linnik, and C. R. Rao, Characterization problems in mathematical statistics. Translated from the Russian by B. Ramachandran, John Wiley & Sons, New York-London-Sydney, 1973.
Theorems 4.2.1, 4.2.1' in Chapter 4.
